# Error 400: Invalid Time Period When Querying Air Quality API with Specific Dates

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-api, google-air-quality-api

I'm currently working on an application where I need to fetch historical air quality data. I'm using the Air Quality API provided by Google and have encountered a 400 Bad Request error with the message stating that the specified time period is not supported.

Here's the code snippet that constructs and sends the HTTP POST request:

```
public getAirQualityData(lat: number, lng: number) {
  const url = `https://airquality.googleapis.com/v1/history:lookup?key=${apiKey}`;
  const thirtyDaysAgo = new Date(Date.now() - 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  const body = {
    period: {
      startTime:"2023-10-10T02:00:00Z",
      endTime:"2023-11-10T12:00:00Z"
    },
    location: {
      latitude: 37.419734,
      longitude: -122.0827784
    }
  };
  const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
  return this.http.post(url, body, { headers });
}
```

And here's the error response I received:

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The specified time period is not supported. Please check the provided input and try a different (e.g. shorter) time period or contact support in.",
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

I am puzzled because I am using a time range starting from a date thirty days ago until the current date. I've checked the official documentation but couldn't find specific details regarding the valid time period for historical data requests.

Does anyone have experience with this API who can advise on the proper way to set the time period for historical data requests? I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on what I might be doing wrong or any alternative approaches that could be recommended.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: did you *try a different (e.g. shorter) time period*?

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for your answer.
Yes I tried using a diiference of 2 hours between two same dates and it's not working either...

Comment: same dates 30 days ago, or perhaps, yesterday? (I know the API states "up to 30 days ago" technically 10/10/2023 is 31 days ago ...)

Comment: @JaromandaX when i use the attribute "hours": "4" to get the last 4 hours its working correctly. I think the issue is with period attribute

Comment: You're right it was 31 days instead of 30. It's working now. THank you very much